# Grails criteria query with fetchMode eager with two levels

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, eager

In my Grails project, I have the following classes:

```
class A {
    static hasMany = [cs:C]
}

class B {
    static hasMany = [cs:C]
}

class C {
    static belongsTo = [a:A, b:B]
}
```

I would like to query the class A and bring the all the associations from B and C eagerly. 
I tried the following criteria query, but when I iterate over Cs from A, hibernate uses lazy initialization to query B objects.

```
A.withCriteria() {
    fetchmode "cs", FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode "cs.b", FetchMode.JOIN
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Solved.

```
A.withCriteria() {
    cs{
        fetchMode "cs.b", FetchMode.JOIN
    }
}
```

Or

```
A.withCriteria() {
    cs{
        b{
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases Hibernate is using two queries. Much better than the 98 I had before ;-)

Comment: i had a similar problem on `one-to-many` and the `FetchMode.SELECT` solved it for me.